# Navigation bar image stays after back button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, pushviewcontroller, navigationbar

I'm using a navigation controller  with a menu. In this menu , the navigation controller is called to push other view controllers.
I've set the color of the navigation bar in the menu with this code  :

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

and I 've set in  controllers different images for the background image of the navigation bar with :

```
UIImage *barreCinema = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barre concert.png"];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:barreCinema forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But when I'm on the controller , and I pressed the back button , the iamge background of the navigation bar stays the same in the menu ..

Hope you understand
Thanks!

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: Oh Sorry !    I'm using Objective-C in iOS

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `self.navigationcontroller` in the first and second view controller is the same navigation controller. So if you set the background image in the first view controller, then change the image in the second view controller, once you pop back the image will remain the last thing it was set to. A possible solution to this would be to add the code that sets the background image / colors to the `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` methods of both the first and second view controllers.